# Determine state of a process

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system

I am trying to figure out the state of processes using C (running, sleeping, or exited), in a linux environment.

My thoughts on how to do this initially were to call `execv()` with the command `ps 12345` where 12345 would be the process ID, and then parse the output of that in order to get the STAT. However, I don't think that I can get the output of that into my program, as it just outputs automatically (or can I?).

I was also thinking that I could send the process a signal, but I haven't found a good way to do this, and I don't even know if it is possible to determine the process state in this manner.

So, my question is, how do I determine the state of a process in C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In linux there's a file of space-separated values called `/proc/[pid]/stat`. The third value is the process state.

For example:

```
[cnicutar@fresh self]$ cat /proc/3529/stat
3529 (bash) S 3528 3529 ......
            ^
```

Alternatively, there's also a `/proc/[pid]/status` file:

```
[cnicutar@fresh self]$ cat /proc/3529/status
Name:   bash
State:  S (sleeping)
....................
```

I would just use `fscanf` on `stat`.

Comment: It's good do know that terminal 'e's have been cleaned up so nicely in Linux :-)

Comment: I am fairly new to C, this is the first program I have written in C. So, `fscanf` would work as `fscanf(/proc/[pid]/status, "%s", str)`, where str is `char str[80];`, and this would pick up the first string, which would be `Name:` (the first output of the /proc/[pid]/status)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse the output of a command, use `popen`.

I guess there is an easier way to do this, there must be a C API to access process information... (note: there is also `/proc/12345/status`)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://sourceforge.net/p/readproc/code/ci/master/tree/

you may use `struct Job.status` for this.

```
#include"read_proc.h"
int main(void)
{
   struct Root * root=read_proc();
   printf("state: %c\n",root->first->status);
   return 0;
}
```